# Добавить к матрице строку и вставить ее под номером

Tags: python, numpy

Как с помощью библиотеки numpy добавить к матрице строку и вставить ее под нужным номером?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [numpy.insert(...)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
In [68]: A = np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3))

In [69]: A
Out[69]:
array([[4, 7, 5],
       [4, 2, 2],
       [6, 3, 2],
       [5, 7, 3],
       [6, 2, 8]])

In [70]: A = np.insert(A, [2], [10, 10, 10], axis=0)

In [71]: A
Out[71]:
array([[ 4,  7,  5],
       [ 4,  2,  2],
       [10, 10, 10],    # <--- Вставленная строка
       [ 6,  3,  2],
       [ 5,  7,  3],
       [ 6,  2,  8]])
```